# generate w wildfly project

Tags: maven, wildfly

I started to use Wildfly, the problem that I can't even run the demo, the demo project which is generated by Wildfly.
Every time that I execute the command `mvn wildfly-swarm:run`

I got these errors:

```
     Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2017.1.1:package (default) on project demo: Execution default of goal org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2017.1.1:package failed: A required class was missing while executing org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2017.1.1:package: Lorg/eclipse/aether/impl/ArtifactResolver;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2017.1.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/wildfly-swarm-plugin/2017.1.1/wildfly-swarm-plugin-2017.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/fraction-list/2017.1.1/fraction-list-2017.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/com/eclipsesource/minimal-json/minimal-json/0.9.4/minimal-json-0.9.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/tools/2017.1.1/tools-2017.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/bootstrap/2017.1.1/bootstrap-2017.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/jboss/modules/jboss-modules/1.5.2.Final/jboss-modules-1.5.2.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-api/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-api-1.2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-spi/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-spi-1.2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-impl-base/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-impl-base-1.2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-jboss-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-javaee-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-api-base-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-jboss-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-base-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi/2.0.0-alpha-9/shrinkwrap-descriptors-spi-2.0.0-alpha-9.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-all/5.0.4/asm-all-5.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/wildfly/swarm/spi/2017.1.1/spi-2017.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.20/plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/home/../.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-api/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-api-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.eclipse.aether.impl.ArtifactResolver
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginC
```

Comment: Which wildfly-swarm example are you running ? and what is your maven version ?

Comment: The demo example, I generate it from http://wildfly-swarm.io/ 

Maven version : Apache Maven 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

The JDK 8 is required to build and run WildFly Swarm applications.

The Maven Plugin, that performs most of the work when packaging WildFly Swarm applications requires at maven 3.3.x

Answer (score 0):

WildFly swarm requires requires Maven 3.2.1 or later.